# merging pandas DataFrames after resampling

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe, merge

I have a DataFramewith with a datetime index.

```
df1=pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range('20100201', periods=24, freq='8h3min'),
                data=np.random.rand(24),columns=['Rubbish'])
df1.index=df1.index.to_datetime()
```

I want to resample this DataFrame, as in :

```
df1=df1.resample('7D').agg(np.median)
```

Then I have another DataFrame, with index of different frequency and starting at a different offset hour

```
df2=pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range('20100205', periods=24, freq='6h3min'),
                data=np.random.rand(24),columns=['Rubbish'])
df2.index=df2.index.to_datetime()
df2=df2.resample('7D').agg(np.median)
```

The operations work well independently, but when I try to merge the results using

```
print(pd.merge(df1,df2,right_index=True,left_index=True,how='outer'))
```

I get:

```
Rubbish_x  Rubbish_y
2010-02-01   0.585986        NaN
2010-02-05        NaN   0.423316
2010-02-08   0.767499        NaN
```

While I would like to resample both with same offset, and get the following result after a merge

```
            Rubbish_x  Rubbish_y
2010-02-01   AVALUE        AVALUE
2010-02-08   AVALUE        AVALUE
```

I have tried the following, but it only generates nans

```
df2.reindex(df1.index)

print(pd.merge(df1,df2,right_index=True,left_index=True,how='outer'))
```

---

I have to stick to `pandas 0.20.1`.

I have tried `mergeas_of`

```
df1.index
Out[48]: Index([2015-03-24, 2015-03-31, 2015-04-07, 2015-04-14, 2015-04-21, 2015-04-28], dtype='object')

df2.index
Out[49]: Index([2015-03-24, 2015-03-31, 2015-04-07, 2015-04-14, 2015-04-21, 2015-04-28], dtype='object')
output=pd.merge_asof(df1,df2,left_index=True,right_index=True)
```

but it crashes with following traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe need [`merge_asof`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge_asof.html):

```
print(pd.merge_asof(df1,df2,right_index=True,left_index=True))
            Rubbish_x  Rubbish_y
2010-02-01   0.446505        NaN
2010-02-08   0.474330   0.606826
```

Or parameter `method='nearest'` to [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
df2 = df2.reindex(df1.index, method='nearest')
print (df2)
             Rubbish
2010-02-01  0.415248
2010-02-08  0.415248

print(pd.merge(df1,df2,right_index=True,left_index=True,how='outer'))
            Rubbish_x  Rubbish_y
2010-02-01   0.431966   0.415248
2010-02-08   0.279121   0.415248
```

Comment: I have edited the answer, I have troubles with mergeasof

Comment: @00__00__00 - hmmm, if there are same index values then `merge` is enough, not necessary `merge_asof`

Comment: @00__00__00 - super :)

Comment: actually, it still gives problem. it works fine as long as the first index of df2 is after the first index of df1. when that is not the case, I still get inconsistent index as in the question

Comment: problems is: in general I will not know whether the first index in df1 is later or earlier than df2

Comment: 00__00__00 hmmm, it seems both indexes are generally not matched. So what are rules, is possible specify them? I have one idea - change `method='nearest'` to `method='ffill'` or method='bfill'.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172697/discussion-between-00-00-00-and-jezrael).

Answer (score 1):

I think follow code base would achieve your task.

```
>>> index = pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=9, freq='T')
>>> series = pd.Series(range(9), index=index)
>>> series
2000-01-01 00:00:00    0
2000-01-01 00:01:00    1
2000-01-01 00:02:00    2
2000-01-01 00:03:00    3
2000-01-01 00:04:00    4
2000-01-01 00:05:00    5
2000-01-01 00:06:00    6
2000-01-01 00:07:00    7
2000-01-01 00:08:00    8
Freq: T, dtype: int64

>>> series.resample('3T').sum()
2000-01-01 00:00:00     3
2000-01-01 00:03:00    12
2000-01-01 00:06:00    21
Freq: 3T, dtype: int64
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html

Comment: I am sorry but I can not see how this answer the question